# Eclipse indirectly referenced .class file

Tags: spring

When i build the project i am getting this error

```
The type org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Answer (score 5):

Vaelyr answers above is correct
but To be very specific, you need to add spring-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar into your eclipse build path.

Use the spring version that corresponds to your other spring jars.

Answer (score 4):

The class you are trying to use is not apparently on your classpath. Add your Spring jar files to your sources classpath and it should work. If that's not the case do Project -> Clean as well.